# How can to read the full path of file when select from elm form ?

Tags: forms, file, input, elm

I'm going to use FileReader library of Simon

https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader/blob/master/examples/Ex1-Input.elm

I know NativeFile :

type alias NativeFile =
    { name : String
    , size : Int
    , mimeType : Maybe MimeType.MimeType
    , blob : FileRef
    }

How can to read the full path of file when select from elm form ?

Thanks for your library, Simon

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't.

For security reasons browsers do not allow access to the file system. Note this is not a limitation of Elm. The HTML5 File API simply doesn't allow that.